# Use horizontal scroll to switch workspace with Compiz

Tags: compiz, mouse, 13.10, touchpad, workspaces

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy.

I want to find a way to use horizontal scrolling to switch workspaces. I'm using Compiz 3D cube right now, but I'm not horribly attached to it.

I'm looking for behavior similar to how Chrome works to switch between "Most Visited" and "Apps" on the new tab page using horizontal scroll, but for workspaces.

The only reference I've found to something like this is [here](http://iloveubuntu.net/how-easily-enable-workspace-switching-mouse-wheel-ubuntu-1110).

However, that option isn't available in the current version of Ubuntu Tweak, and anyway it says it only works when the cursor is on the desktop (so I can't do it if I have a window maximized.)

Is this possible?

Comment: Too bad this hasn't been answered yet; I was looking for the same thing. I just think that it is worth mentioning, in case you don't know about it, that you can easily switch between workspaces by using CTRL+ALT+arrow_keys

Comment: Yeah, I use that - works okay. I just got my hands on a friend's Macbook and realized the swipe-to-change-workspace is pretty slick. :)

Comment: `it only works when the cursor is on the desktop` That's because most applications bind the scroll to the scroll up/down feature, like scrolling a page up and down on your browser. I don't think you can (or should) override that behavior when a window with that key biding is active. Perhaps moving the mouse to the taskbar and then using said feature would work?

Answer (score 1):

[xSwipe](https://github.com/iberianpig/xSwipe) should be able to help you. It is able to bind several multi-touch gestures to keybindings (like CTRL+ALT+arrow_keys).

There is one issue with it that is uses older synclient and requires option -m to be availible. Fix to that is to install forked synaptic drivers ([instructions](http://blog.mpiannucci.com/view/multitouchgesture))

Comment: I couldn't get it working. When I run xSwipe interactively (in a terminal), I occasionally get control characters printed out when I do various swipe actions, but it's not reliable, and I can't for the life of me get the swipes to actually do anything - for example, the swipe action that sends a <Ctrl>+<Alt>+Left to change workspaces doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: Never mind! It seems to use the keybindings for "Other" rather than the ones for Ubuntu by default. It works, thanks!